# React Native Navigation props undefined on pushed screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new to react native and I followed the Authentication flows tutorial from react native. Now I'm using typescript and I think that has something to do with it. Because when I just copy the javascript example it works.

```
export default class SignInScreen extends Component<NavigationScreenProps> {

    constructor(props: NavigationScreenProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Sign in</Text>
                <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this.signIn}/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    private async signIn() {
        //await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
        console.log("PROPS", this.props);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});
```

AuthLoadingScreen

```
export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component<NavigationScreenProps> {

    constructor(props: NavigationScreenProps) {
        super(props);
        this.bootstrap();
    }

    private async bootstrap() {
        console.log("AUTH props", this.props);
        try {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error', err.message);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator />
                <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

App.tsx

```
const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

Now on the AuthLoadingScreen the props are not undefined and I push to the SignInScreen but when I click on the button the props are undefined. I have no idea why because all the examples I find are doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this` is not within the context you expect it to be. The function is unbounded, so `this` doesn't contain `props`. Here's how you  bind it:

```
<Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)}/>
```

You can also use the following, without `bind`ing:

```
<Button title="Sign in!" onPress={() => { this.signIn() }}/>
```

Although I prefer the first example.